# Swift AnyObject to Int always ends up as nil

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make an AnyObject? become and Int but its just not working for me. Where am I going wrong?

```
let user = ParseUser(json)
let user_id = user["user_id"] as? Int

print(user)
print(user_id)
```

and this prints

```
["user_id": 361, "gender": female, "email": ddd@gmail.com, "name": Bob]
nil
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `ParseUser(json)` function. The `user_id` here is not Int. You can check with this dictionary:

```
// Why gender, email and name field is not String?
// What type of them is that?
let user = ["user_id": 361, "gender": "female", "email": "ddd@gmail.com", "name": "Bob"]
let user_id = user["user_id"] as? Int

// Successfully printed "(Optional)361"
print(user_id)
```

Comment: How do I have an array of mixed Int's and Strings. I created the array as var user = [String: AnyObject]()
This is what ParseUser returns

Comment: You created a `Dictionary`, not an array. And you created it right, but maybe you set `user_id` field wrong. You must set it like this: `user["user_id"] = 361`

Comment: Thanks i was just setting the value wrong to being with

Answer (score 0):

If the underlying type is `String` which is in most cases, you can use following code:

```
let id = Int(foo as! String)!
```

Comment: I get cannot invoke initializer for type with an argument list of type '(AnyObject?)'

Comment: How are you parsing the JSON? What's the type? If it's a normal parsing and it's `String`, you can use the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast to `NSString` first which are object. Once you have it, you may assign to variable of the type Int.

```
let user_id = (user["user_id"] as? NSString)?.integerValue
```

You may try following [snippet](http://iswift.org/playground?JoqFgu):

```
var user: [String: AnyObject] = ["user_id": "361"]

let user_id = (user["user_id"] as? NSString)?.integerValue

print(user_id)
```

Which output is:

```
Optional(361)
```

BTW, you may check actual type of the variable using `dynamicType` property:

```
user["user_id"]!.dynamicType
```